# Which firefox.desktop prevails?

Tags: firefox, indicator

If there is a firefox.desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`, does it override the firefox.desktop in `/usr/share/applications`? If not, is there a way to make it do so?

Answer (score 5):

The one in `~/.local/share/applications` takes precedence over the one in `/usr/share/applications`.